# Is there a way to have a view only be included for Previews, ignoring that view for device and simulator builds?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to have a view only be included for Previews, ignoring that view for device and simulator builds?

Say I have a view X, and I want X to include a view Y only when watched using previews in Xcode. Something like this:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("I am view X")
#if PREVIEWS
    Text("this is only visible in previews")
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no macro for preview mode. However, you can modify `previews` which conform to `PreviewProvider`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Real view")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            ContentView()

            Text("PREVIEWING")
        }
    }
}
```

Output here, the view on the right is just available when previewing.

[image]